# Bokeh Plotting with EC2 Public DNS Argument

Tags: python, plot, anaconda, bokeh

How can I specify an EC2 DNS URL to use as localhost for Bokeh Server plotting? Came across a couple of posts that mention that you can pass a url to `bokeh.plotting.output_server(docname, session=None, url='default', name=None)` but then I also noticed that there is an --ip option for bokeh-server. Still not sure how exactly to make it so that I can just navigate to https://publicdns.com/5006 to be able to host the plots. Any help would be appreciated. I did try the --ip flag option by passing my dns url but received a trackback error.

Answer (score 0):

By default the bokeh server only listens on `127.0.0.1` if you want to listen on a different ip, that is what the `--ip` argument is for. If you want to listen on all interfaces, you can pass `--ip 0.0.0.0` when you start it.

Comment: Thank you but I tried to do exactly that using my public dns ec2 url and server seems to start but then a few seconds later I get `RuntimeError: cannot join thread before it is started`

Comment: Are you sure you killed all the previous Python processes, etc.?

Also, posting the entire traceback would be helpful for understanding the problem.